# python pandas coloring of rows

Tags: python, html, css, pandas

I have this code that colors every time slot differently, so it is easier to navigate. The problem is, sometimes not all the slots will be populated and then i get the same color on the next slot and it will be hard to distinguish which slot is which.
how can i make this code more elegant and make python decide when there is a next slot to change the color. i want to have those colors changed "binary".

```
def EPP_Break_boja(row):
    color = '#F5EEF8'
    if row.values[0] == '06:40':
        color = '#EBF5FB  '
    elif row.values[0] == '07:10':
        color = '#FEF9E7  '
    elif row.values[0] == '07:40':
        color = '#EBF5FB  '
    elif row.values[0] == '08:10':
        color = '#FEF9E7  '
    elif row.values[0] == '08:40':
        color = '#EBF5FB  '
    elif row.values[0] == '09:10':
        color = '#FEF9E7  '
    elif row.values[0] == '09:40':
        color = '#EBF5FB  '
    elif row.values[0] == '10:10':
        color = '#FEF9E7  '
    elif row.values[0] == '10:40':
        color = '#EBF5FB  '
    elif row.values[0] == '11:10':
        color = '#FEF9E7  '
    elif row.values[0] == '11:40':
        color = '#EBF5FB  '
    elif row.values[0] == '12:10':
        color = '#FEF9E7  '
    elif row.values[0] == '12:40':
        color = '#EBF5FB  '
    elif row.values[0] == '13:10':
        color = '#FEF9E7  '
    elif row.values[0] == '13:40':
        color = '#EBF5FB  '
    elif row.values[0] == '14:10':
        color = '#FEF9E7  '
    elif row.values[0] == '14:40':
        color = '#EBF5FB  '
    elif row.values[0] == '15:10':
        color = '#FEF9E7  '
    elif row.values[0] == '15:40':
        color = '#EBF5FB  '
    elif row.values[0] == '16:10':
        color = '#FEF9E7  '
    elif row.values[0] == '16:40':
        color = '#EBF5FB  '
    elif row.values[0] == '17:10':
        color = '#FEF9E7  '
    elif row.values[0] == '17:40':
        color = '#EBF5FB  '
    elif row.values[0] == '18:10':
        color = '#FEF9E7  '
    elif row.values[0] == '18:40':
        color = '#EBF5FB  '
    elif row.values[0] == '19:10':
        color = '#FEF9E7  '
    elif row.values[0] == '19:40':
        color = '#EBF5FB  '
    elif row.values[0] == '20:10':
        color = '#FEF9E7  '
    elif row.values[0] == '20:40':
        color = '#EBF5FB  '
    elif row.values[0] == '21:10':
        color = '#FEF9E7  '
    elif row.values[0] == '21:40':
        color = '#EBF5FB  '
    elif row.values[0] == '22:10':
        color = '#FEF9E7  '
    elif row.values[0] == '22:40':
        color = '#EBF5FB  '
    elif row.values[0] == '23:10':
        color = '#FEF9E7  '
    elif row.values[0] == '23:40':
        color = '#EBF5FB  '
    elif row.values[0] == 'Thursday 12-October-2017':
        color = '#FDEDEC  '
    elif row.values[0] == 'Thursday 13-October-2017':
        color = '#EAFAF1'
    return ['background-color: %s' % color]*len(row.values)


dataframe_spotovi = dataframe_spotovi.style.apply(EPP_Break_boja, axis=1)
dataframe_spotovi
```

Answer (score 1):

what about the following approach:

```
In [112]: colors=['#EBF5FB  ','#FEF9E7  ']

In [113]: df
Out[113]:
    Time title     x
0  06:40     a  2011
1  06:40     b  2010
2  07:10     c  2000
3  08:10     d  1983

In [114]: df.assign(col=np.take(colors, df.groupby('Time').ngroup() % 2))
Out[114]:
    Time title     x        col
0  06:40     a  2011  #EBF5FB
1  06:40     b  2010  #EBF5FB
2  07:10     c  2000  #FEF9E7
3  08:10     d  1983  #EBF5FB
```

Comment: that would  just color every other rowcin the se color, regardless of value in the row. for example if col0 value at index 0 was also at indexes 1,23 and 4, i want to have rows 0-4 colored in #EBF5FB.

Comment: `d = {'x' : [2011, 2010, 2000, 1983],
    'Time' : ['06:40', '06:40', '07:10', '08:10'],
    'title' : ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}
df =pd.DataFrame(d)
df`

Comment: i would like to have 06:40 in color 1, 07:10 in color nr 2 and then 08:10 back in color 1